# Why is text width while using FONTCONFIG_PATH are always rounded

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, chromium

I am running chrome and chromium and behavior remains same both browsers.

If I don't set FONTCONFIG_PATH environment variable for the browser process, I see floating point numbers such as 136.2060546875. If I set FONTCONFIG_PATH, I get rounded numbers such as 136, no fractional part. Using following Javascript to get the width

```
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = 'sans-serif';
let tm = ctx.measureText("hello world");
console.log(tm.width);
```

Why do I always get rounded numbers while using FONTCONFIG_PATH? Fonts are available and config path is correct.